# Sharing Arduino pin 11 MISO and PWM

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit

I need exactly 6 PWM pins and PWM pin 11 is MOSI on Arduino nano. I use SD card to read configuration when program starts and to log few things later.

I would like to use CS pin for SD card module and when it is 1 to turn on MOSI transistor, or turn on PWM transistor when it is 0.

Is there any IC that has two inputs, one output and switch to select them?
What would you use to make this if space is limited?

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "multiplexer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the same output pin for two devices, so you'd need to multiplex in the other direction (i.e. one input, two outputs).

The SD card already does that for you, it will completely ignore MOSI if its CS is unset -- that's the point of having a CS line.

So all that is left is having the other device ignore its PWM input and keep the previous state while you are addressing the SD card. Depending on the device, it may already have readymade logic for that, or it might not work at all because interrupting the PWM line will make it turn off.

Comment: I somehow did not realise that I need only to disable PWM output and that SD card does that. I will use one transistor to disable PWM part. Thanks